# Put a gree nborder on the item selected from the List View

Tags: flutter

For the below code there is a listview and on clicking any item on the list i just want to have a green border on the right .
This is the implementation that i am using , on clicking i am saving the index in the state and then checking the state to select the color .

The issue is optimization , i can see the whole list if getting loaded due to state changes .. ca we just make the item with border without loading the whole list.

```
            class SubCategoriesGrid extends StatefulWidget {
              SubCategoriesGrid();
            
              @override
              State<SubCategoriesGrid> createState() => _SubCategoriesGridState();
            }
            
            class _SubCategoriesGridState extends State<SubCategoriesGrid> {
              int pressedAttentionIndex = -1;
            
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                print('Loading the list ');
                final subcategoriesData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
                Future<QuerySnapshot> subCategoriesData =
                    subcategoriesData.getSubCategories();
                return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  future: subCategoriesData,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                      );
                    }
                    final subCategories = snapshot.data!.docs;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: subCategories.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final subCategory = subCategories[index];
                        return verticleScrollContainer(
                            "assets/images/blink/" + subCategory["imageURL"], index);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            
              Widget verticleScrollContainer(var image, index) {
                print('index ' + index.toString());
                print('Loading the widget');
                print('pressedAttentionIndex ' + pressedAttentionIndex.toString());
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('on tapping');
                    setState(() {
                      pressedAttentionIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        right: BorderSide(
                          color: pressedAttentionIndex == index
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.grey, // Color of the border on the right side
                          width: 4.0, // green of the border
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            radius: 32,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: ClipOval(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                image,
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('Name'),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
```

Comment: I guess the major issue is you're making and assigning subcategoriesData and subCategoriesData variable in the build method and using FutureBuilder, so on every-time on setState; your these variable made again and and future method is called. You need to use cubit or bloc instead of FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can simply change color of your listview builder with this   


 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class SubCategoriesGrid extends StatefulWidget {
      SubCategoriesGrid();
    
      @override
      State<SubCategoriesGrid> createState() => _SubCategoriesGridState();
    }
    
    class _SubCategoriesGridState extends State<SubCategoriesGrid> {
      int? currentIndex;
      void changeIndex(int index) {
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = index;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print('Loading the list ');
        final subcategoriesData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
        Future<QuerySnapshot> subCategoriesData =
            subcategoriesData.getSubCategories();
        return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: subCategoriesData,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              );
            }
            final subCategories = snapshot.data!.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: subCategories.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final subCategory = subCategories[index];
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    changeIndex(index);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        right: BorderSide(
                          color: currentIndex == index
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.grey, // Color of the border on the right side
                          width: 4.0, // green of the border
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            radius: 32,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: ClipOval(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/blink/",
                                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text('Name'),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: still it's the same, it will rebuild the whole tree and Future function and will called everytime.

Comment: use State Management if you didn't want to rebuild the whole tree

Comment: yeah thats what i'm telling!

Comment: Many of your recent answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.  Using your own words to even *summarize* content that you found elsewhere still requires attribution of the original source. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: its not AI generated....its my own code...i have test it in my own system...you even don't know about original content or AI generated content..